# Get the variable x to not be the list index, but the actual value from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to get the max value from a list. We are not allowed to use the max function and have to use a while loop in this example.

im stuck right now since when I run this code "large = x" doesnt actually put the value from the list in to the variable x but the index its at and I cant seem to fix that.

```
def get_max_while(integer_list):
    x = integer_list
    i = 0
    while i <= len(x):
        largest = 0
        large = x
        if largest < large:
            largest = large
    return

get_max_while([3, 8, 4,7])
```

Answer (score 1):

**4 points**:

- `largest` should be initialised to 0 outside `while` loop.
- `while` condition should be `<`, or else you will run into `IndexError`.
- You should increment `i` in loop, or else it's going to be an infinite loop.
- Lastly, there is no need of separate variable `x`, you can use `integer_list` itself.

**Code**:

```
def get_max_while(integer_list):
    largest, i = 0, 0
    while i < len(integer_list):
        large = integer_list[i]
        if largest < large:
            largest = large
        i += 1
    return largest

print(get_max_while([3, 8, 4,7]))
```

Answer (score 0):

largest is in the loop so it gets reset every time you go into the loop. Try taking it out. Also in order to get an element from the list you have to use list[index] in your case x[i]